# Build-time validation of web sockets ClientEndpoint in Quarkus

Tags: java, validation, cdi, quarkus, eclipse-jee

I use Java WebSocket API to declare client (Java class annotated by @ClientEndpoint):

```
@ClientEndpoint
public class MySock {
    MySock(ExecutorService exec){}
    ...
}
```

Instance is created via constructor:

```
webSocket = new MySock(exec);
session = wsContainer.connectToServer(webSocket, url);
```

And I have error during the build via quarkus-maven-plugin:

```
[error]: Build step ...ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: 
javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException:
Unsatisfied dependency for type ...ExecutorService and qualifiers [@Default]
- java member: edu.MySock#<init>()
- declared on CLASS bean [types=[edu.MySock, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=edu.MySock]
```

**Pay attention: there is no @Inject annotation**

Should have it been validated, if it can be passed to #connectToServer as a class and as instance too?

So,  Is it ok if validation processes a pessimistic case, where validation is useful, but it brokes an optimistic case?

Pessimistic case, where dependencies may not be declared:

```
session = wsContainer.connectToServer(MySock.class, url);
```

In the following case, validation is harmful because it brokes build phase:

```
session = wsContainer.connectToServer(webSocket, url);
```

Maybe ClientEndpoint should not be validated at all?

---

And before you ask me... 
We are not going to inject something into WebSocket and we would not like to use programmatic EndPoints. But we want to create an instance for the annotated class. Why not? WebSocket incapsulates complex logic inside itself and this variant we used multiple times (e. g. in applications on WildFly).

---

***The best solution*** for me would be to disable validation for my bean only, but I cannot find an idea of how to do it.

*This article has not helped me https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference. The fact that [beans.xml is ignored](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/1525) cannot help me too.*

***The second-way***, for the future, is to disable validation if there is no one class member with @Inject annotation. It can be not correct, but [here](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html) there is some explanation:

> First, the container calls the bean constructor (the default constructor or the one annotated @Inject), to obtain an instance of the bean.

*So, my constructor is not "default" and I did not use @Inject annotation.*

Answer (score 1):

Work around is so simple: @javax.enterprise.inject.Vetoed annotation disables bean for validation.